# What is the difference between XmlWebApplicationContext, AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext, and GenericWebApplicationContext

Tags: java, spring, testng, spring-test

I am writing a unit test with TestNG and spring-test that is loading the xml contexts by `@ContextConfiguration` and loading the dispatcher servlet by `@WebAppConfiguration`. I have a class like blow that gets the context and prints the context type.

```java
@Component
public class ApplicationContextInitializer implements ApplicationContextAware {


    @Override
    public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext applicationContext) throws BeansException {
        ApplicationContextInitializer.applicationContext = applicationContext;
        if (applicationContext instanceof AnnotationConfigApplicationContext) {
            System.out.println("1");
        }

        if (applicationContext instanceof GenericWebApplicationContext) {
            System.out.println("3");
        }

        if (applicationContext instanceof GenericXmlApplicationContext) {
            System.out.println("4");
        }

        if (applicationContext instanceof ResourceAdapterApplicationContext) {
            System.out.println("5");
        }

        if (applicationContext instanceof StaticApplicationContext) {
            System.out.println("6");
        }

        if (applicationContext instanceof XmlWebApplicationContext) {
            System.out.println("7");
        }

        if (applicationContext instanceof AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext) {
            System.out.println("8");
        }
    }
}
```

Test class:

```java
@ContextConfiguration(value = "classpath:integration-context-test.xml")
@TestPropertySource(locations = {"classpath:temp.properties"})
@WebAppConfiguration
public class TaskTest extends AbstractTransactionalTestNGSpringContextTests {}
```

Why the console prints `"3"`, showing that it is `GenericWebApplicationContext`? When will it return two other types mentioned? Is it possible to get `XmlWebApplicationContext`in written `ApplicationContextInitializer` class while using TestNG?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why the console prints `"3"`, showing that it is `GenericWebApplicationContext`?

In an integration test using the *Spring TestContext Framework*, the `ApplicationContext` is a `GenericWebApplicationContext` if you annotate your test class with `@WebAppConfiguration`. Otherwise, it would be a `GenericApplicationContext`.

The `ApplicationContext` for an integration test is loaded by a `ContextLoader`. In your example, the concrete implementation is a `GenericXmlWebContextLoader`. That's because you specify `locations` for an XML config file.

> When will it return two other types mentioned?

In an integration test, it won't return the other types you mentioned, since all `ContextLoader` implementations in the *Spring TestContext Framework* create either a `GenericApplicationContext` or a `GenericWebApplicationContext`.

> Is it possible to get `XmlWebApplicationContext` in written `ApplicationContextInitializer` class while using TestNG?

No, not in a test.

But you typically shouldn't need to rely on it being an `XmlWebApplicationContext`. Knowing that it is a `ConfigurableWebApplicationContext` (and therefore a `WebApplicationContext`) should usually be sufficient both in production code and in tests.